# Find out if two string inputs are anagram, ignoring white spaces, punctuation, and numbers

Tags: c++, validation, anagram

I am trying to find out if two string inputs are an anagram. The program has to ignore white spaces, punctuation, and numbers.

I have a function that validates each character in the input stream. When I run the program, it puts two white spaces after I input the first string. It also gives the wrong output.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string>
#define No_of_chars 26

using namespace std;
const int SIZE = 26;
int count1[No_of_chars]={0};
               
// finds the strings are anagram
bool areAnagram(string str1, string str2)
{
    // Get lengths of both strings
    int n1 = str1.length();
    int n2 = str2.length();

    // If length of both strings is not same, then they cannot be anagram
    if (n1 != n2)
        return false;

    // Sort both the strings
    sort(str1.begin(), str1.end());
    sort(str2.begin(), str2.end());

    // Compare sorted strings
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        if (str1[i] != str2[i])
            return false;
}

// validate each character in the input string
void validateCharacter(string sentence)
{
    char ch;
    int count = 0;

    cin.get(ch);
    while(ch >= ' ' && count < SIZE)
    {
        if (isalpha(ch))
        {
            cin.ignore();
        }

        sentence=ch;

        count++;
        cin.get(ch);
    }
}

int main()
{
    string s1;
    string s2;
    cout<< "Csci Anagram Strings Program"<<endl;

    cout << "enter something ->";
    validateCharacter(s1);

    cout << "enter something ->";
    validateCharacter(s2);

    if(areAnagram(s1, s2))
        cout << "The two strings are anagram of each other";
    else
        cout << "The two strings are not anagram of each other";

    return 0;
}
```

Getting wrong output:

```
Csci Anagram Strings Program                                                                                                                           
enter something ->kkk                                                                                                                                  
enter something ->kkk   
The two strings are not anagram of each other
```

Comment: areAnagram doesn't return true in any case? Seems to not return anything if the strings are anagrams.

Comment: What is `sentence=ch` supposed to do?  Also, pass it by reference, not by value (or drop the parameter entirely and return a std::string as the function result).  And please don't spam language tags (fixed - it's C++, not C).

Comment: Also, sorting will give you nlogn complexity. You could step through in n and use a hashmap for the count of each letter.

Comment: oh my anagram function wasn't returning true. Thanks, but it is returning true for every input now .Might have something to do with the character validation.Am using cin.get() to process every character but am getting a big space when i press enter on the keyboard before i get prompted for the second string, why?  @Paul Sander Ok.

Comment: I would recommend using `cin >> my_string_variable` and then remove the unwanted characters afterwards.

Comment: @Paul Sanders,thanks but i'm required to use cin.get() for this particular assignment.

Comment: What do you expect with     sentence=ch;  ?

Comment: That was an error, it should have been sentence+=ch @2785528. I want to collect all the valid characters read by cin.get() to sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `return true;` at the end of your `areAnagram` function.

Comment: Yes i did correct but am still getting wrong output